# 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqlclient

I am trying to read the list of state from the db table into @html.dropdownlistfor in the data entry form that I am writing.
I am using `SqlClient` in my controller to achieve this. Below is the code for controller and view page.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DataEntry() 
        {
            var query = "SELECT State, Description FROM dbo.CountryState WHERE Country = 'USA'";
 //I declared the connection string in the beginning of the controller as below
//string cnn = "Server=mydb;Database=db_registry_data;Trusted_Connection=True;";

            List<DataForm> stateList = new List<DataForm>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        DataForm dataForm = new DataForm();
                        dataForm.Description = Convert.ToString(reader["Description"]); // description: full name of state
                        dataForm.State = Convert.ToString(reader["State"]); //state: initials of the state

                        stateList.Add(dataForm);
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            ViewBag.States = stateList;
            return View(); 
        }
```

Here is my view page

```
@model DataEntry.Models.DataForm

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

@using (Html.BeginForm("DataEntry", "DataForm", new { @class = "form-control", style = "display: flex;" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputEmail4">State: </label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(ViewBag.States, "State","Description"), "--Please Select--", new { @class = "form-control"})
    </div>
}
```

Finally, I am getting the following error when I try to run the project.

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.)'
>
> Win32Exception: The target principal name is incorrect.

I would love sone help to fix this error. Thank you!

P.S. I didn't post the `[HttpPost]` one of the function since it pulls the form successfully before adding `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(ViewBag.States, "State","Description"), "--Please Select--", new { @class = "form-control"})` part in the view page.

Comment: You can get more details by checking the log file using SQL Server Management Studio in the explorer under Management.

Comment: By the looks of things, you are trying to use Kerberos authentication for SQL Server, and something is failing. For this to work properly, SQL Server needs to run under a domain account (possibly a MSA or gMSA) and the webserver also needs to. Both machines need to be joined to the same AD domain. And SQL Server needs to register an SPN (normally happens automatically). If the webserver is impersonating a user (using client certificates or password), then that user needs to be an AD user, and the SQL Server's account needs to be setup with either Constrained Delegation or RBCD.

Comment: Isn't the problem the SSL certificate? Are you using the built-in self signed cert or your own? If the built-in you either need to force the trust or not use an encrypted connection. If your own, the name of the server you used to connect and those in the cert don't match.

Comment: Aside... `SqlCommand` is an `IDisposable` as well, you should ensure that it's always in a `using` reference so that it gets disposed of correctly and doesn't leak resources.

Comment: If you're using the modern `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` assembly, version 5.0 or later, you have the `HostNameInCertificate` [connection string property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring) available so as to match the target server's certificate name when it doesn't match its DNS name.

Comment: well I am doing the same as the other project I did before. The server name and db name are correct but I don't know why it just won't pull the data

Comment: *"The server name and db name are correct but I don't know why it just won't pull the data"* This isn't what I mean by the names don't match. When you create a certificate, for SQL Server to use for SSL, you define in the cert the name of the host running the service, as well as alternative names and IPs. If, for example, you connected uses a full domain path, MyServer.MyDomain.local perhaps, but the cert only had the host name, MyServer, they would *not* match and you would likely get the above error as well. This is why I asked if you're using the built in cert or your own.

Answer (score 2):

I added `Encrypt=False;` at the end of the connection string and it worked like a charm. Thanks everyone for your time to help me.

Comment: Adding `TrustServerCertificate=true;` solved the problem for me, without disabling encryption. For me the problem was caused by the SQL Server using a server certificate which the client hadn't added to its list of trusted certificates.